# How to get totals and count Items from Tabulator 4.9.3

Tags: tabulator

Thank you for help us

I want to get Totals and count Items from Tabulator and put it in Variable I can save it in Database SQL Server

I try to search in tabulator help for Examples or Questions like that problem

[Image Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUrUf.png)

Comment: `table.getCalcResults()`